# Error while passing SQL query using stringbuilder in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm passing some arguments to insert the record into the table using StringBuilder, I' m getting error:

> Error 134 Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.

Near 'napproved' where 'napproved' this is a string argument contains 'N'

Here is the code

```
 sb.Append("insert into [DBAccounting].[dbo].[CRS_TaxReport_TaxConsultant]")
 sb.Append(" ([CLIENTCODE],[TC],[SECURITY_NO],[TC_NAME],[ADDRESS],")
 sb.Append("[ACCOUNT_NAME],[ACCOUNT_NO],[PHONE_NO],")
 sb.Append("[EMAIL_IDS],[IsApproved],")
 sb.Append("[ApprovedBy],[ApproveDate],")
 sb.Append("[MakerId],[MakerDt])")
 sb.Append("VALUES('" & txtclientCode.Text & "',")
 sb.Append("'" & txttc.Text & "','" & txtSecNo.Text & "',")
 sb.Append("'" & txtTcName.Text & "','" & txtaddress.Text & "','" & txtaccname.Text & "',")
 sb.Append("'" & txtaccno.Text & "','" & txtphno.Text & "','" & txtMailID.Text & "',")
 sb.Append(" "napproved.ToString" ,"","","approvedby.ToString","Today.ToString")")
```

Comment: Using a StringBuilder to build a sql query is suspicious. Don't concatenate strings to build a query, you're open for sql-injection. Use parametrized queries.

Comment: Could you replace the last line as `sb.Append("'" & napproved.ToString() & "', "", "", '"& approvedby.ToString() & "', '" & Today.ToString() & "')")` and try

Comment: Your code is not correct syntactically. I'm unable to even compile your code even by declaring a string builder variable named sb.

Comment: Your last line ` sb.Append(" "napproved.ToString" ,"","","approvedby.ToString","Today.ToString")")` has got problems